# Get column from a table with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and I want to get the "price" column of data from a table however I'm unable to retrieve that data.

Currently what I'm doing:

```
# Libraies
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table")

for row in table.find_all("tr"):

    col = row.find_all("td")

    print(col[2])
    print("---")
```

I keep getting a list index out of value range. I've read the documentation and tried a few different ways, but I can't seem to get it down.

Also, I am using Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating over all `tr` inside the table, and there is 1 header `tr` at the beginning that you don't need, so just avoid using that one:

```
    # Libraies
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table")

for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:

    col = row.find_all("td")

    print(col[2])
    print("---")
```

Comment: That was the issue. I'll make sure to check the table structure next time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably means that one of the rows has no `td` tag. You could wrap the `print` or whatever usage of `col[2]` in a try except block and ignore cases where the `col` is empty or has less than three items

```
for row in table.find_all("tr"):

    col = row.find_all("td")
    try:  
        print(col[2])
        print("---")
    except IndexError:
        pass
```